# What's the difference between a programme like Media Tomb and Samba

Tags: samba, rhythmbox

I initially found it difficult to get any music player to play my collection which is located on a NAS connected to my Windows desktop. What is the difference between the role that Media Tomb and Samba play in letting me access the files on my NAS? Do I need them both?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need both. You need Samba to join the Workgroup that your NAS is a member of. The default name is "WORKGROUP" but that may vary. In your Files manager, a "Network" item will appear. If you click that, you will be able to access the files on the NAS.

Media Tomb - or any media player - will probably not allow you to play songs on the network straightaway. To do this, you need to create a directory (something like `/media/nas`) where you will put the share. Think of `/media/nas` as a drive letter under Windows. This is a process called mounting. As soon as the NAS is mounted under `/media/nas`, you can access the music as if it was stored locally, and Media Tomb will find it.

If the mount succeeds, you should consider adding a line in `/etc/fstab` to have your NAS automatically mounted the next time you reboot.

Plenty of information on how to install Samba and connect to a workgroup, as well as mounting a share and making sure it is remounted at boot time, is available on this web site.

Comment: Thanks, that's very helpful. I did enough - and can't remember how! - to get Rhythmbox working but my set-up doesn't work for Clementine. Do two such similar-function programmes need different approaches?

Comment: I just took a look and it is indeed possible to use a network share as a Music Library in Rhythmbox. If you do File/Add music..., then from the dropdown list choose "Other...", Rhythmbox will indeed present you with a list of bookmarks, including the "Network" item that I mentioned. Your NAS should turn up there. As far as I can tell, Clementine has no such option. Does that ring a bell? It is however also possible that you use the NAS as a UPnP server. That is a mechanism that completely bypasses Samba, and for which Samba is not required.

Comment: Merci beaucoup. I think the combination of more not-very-techie people like me deserting Windows XP and using a NAS suggests there is growing demand for Ubuntu to "fit as standard" the ability to run stuff like music players on a NAS. PS I really do think this is Linux's opportunity to break through into a much larger market if anyone wants to make it happen.